# Bulk load data conversion error (truncation)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv, bulkinsert

I am getting this error

```
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 12 (is_download)
```

here is the csv...it only has one row

```
30,Bill,Worthy,sales,,709888499,bat@bat.com,,"Im a a people person., to work together for this new emerging env.HTTP://applesoftware.com","Bill and Son of Co","Contact Us: Contact Form",0
```

here is my bulk insert statement...

```
SE SalesLogix
GO

CREATE TABLE CSVTemp
(id INT,
firstname VARCHAR(255),
lastname VARCHAR(255),
department VARCHAR(255),
architecture VARCHAR(255),
phone VARCHAR(255),
email VARCHAR(255),
download VARCHAR(255),
comments VARCHAR(MAX),
company VARCHAR(255),
location VARCHAR(255),
is_download VARCHAR(255)
)
GO

BULK
INSERT CSVTemp
FROM 'c:\leads\leads.csv'
WITH
(
DATAFILETYPE = 'char', 
BATCHSIZE = 50, 
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', 
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' 
)
GO
--Check the content of the table.
SELECT *
FROM CSVTemp
GO
```

The problem is most of the time it works great but in some situations (this being one of them) I get the errors

ANy ideas on what is causing this record to have this error

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's picking up the commas within the comments field as delimiters, because the delimiters are not consistent. The best solution is to insure that all fields are wrapped with double quotes and set `FIELDTERMINATOR` to `'","'`. Alternately, replace the commas with something unlikely to be in the comments (like `~`) and set `FIELDTERMINATOR = '~'`.

Answer (score 12):

In addition to Wil's comments, it seems like it is seeing all 12 columns, so it may just be that your rowterminator is incorrect. First, make sure that the program that puts these files together is in fact putting a carriage return at the end of the last line; I've had to correct many programs where this wasn't the case. Once you are sure there is a carriage return there, you may have to experiment to see what type of carriage return it is. Sometimes it is char(10) only, sometimes char(13) only, and sometimes it may have both but be in the wrong order. So experiment with:

```
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
ROWTERMINATOR = '\r'
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n\r'
ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'
```

Comment: Often if the rowterminator is incorrect or inconsistent it can cause it to combine the rows until it hits the recognized terminator or even eof. I've had that happen before.

Answer (score 7):

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 97, column 33

For the above error, you can check

- **Data type size** of column(e.g. VARCHAR(255)) is if it is sufficient to import data or not.
- AND the **row terminator** e.g.

  - ROWTERMINATOR =  '0x0A'
  - ROWTERMINATOR =  '\n'
  - ROWTERMINATOR =  '\r\n'
- FIELDTERMINATOR

  - Make sure the selected field terminator does not occur with in data. If there is a chance of it, then replace it with some other character e.g. | in the file.

Comment: The ROWTERMINATOR of 0x0A did it for me, not the \n or \r combinations.

Comment: Searching SO for awhile now. The '0x0A' was the one that did it for me. This solution provides multiple solutions related to the error and would potentially solve the error.

Answer (score 1):

i had the header as first row. after i removing it, it was fine.

Comment: you can actually tell SQL Sever to ignore the header row by using this in your bulk insert statement: `FIRSTROW = 2` . This will then skip the header row (the first row) and start inserting data from the 2nd row downward

Answer (score 1):

I had exported format files from SQL 2016 with

```
bcp database1.dbo.table1 format nul -f FMTFLDR\table1.fmt -w -S SERVERNAME -T
```

and imported data to SQL 2017 with

```
BULK INSERT database2.dbo.table1 FROM 'DATAFLDR\table1.data' WITH ( FORMATFILE = 'FMTFLDR\table1.fmt');
```

on a couple of tables for some reason, the export for one of the columns was as `SQLCHAR` and the truncation error reported. When i manually updated the format file to use instead `SQLNCHAR` for that field everything was fine.

the table creations is the same in both instances, but i may have a difference in `database1` and `database2` that i haven't cottoned on to yet :D

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved easily by using the following in your bulk insert:

```
FORMAT ='CSV'
```

This takes care of the commas in a string.

Please select this as answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful if you export/import data from the '.csv' files. Replace all 'NULL' with an empty string.
[image: OriginalData]

[image: ExportData]

Answer (score 0):

If none of the above helps, as in my case, then you need to check if one of the columns of the target table has a dimension lower than in the source table

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).