# SQL Server bulk insert - "Bulk load data conversion error"

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

```
bulk insert dbo.A
FROM 'd:\AData.csv'
WITH 
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

Inserting bulk data into a database, I approached an unexplainable error after review of the suspect data:

> *Msg 4867, Level 16, State 1, Line 6*
>   *Bulk load data conversion error (overflow) for row 1, column 42 (FES).*

Column FES was `tinyint`, now `smallint`. `d:\AData.csv` contains a `2` in row 1, column 42. Are there any other sources for this type of error?

---APPEND---

I'm not sure how to properly post this.

Create Table Script

```
create table AcsBy320082010Hus(
serialnoId bigint,
RT char,
DIVISION tinyint,
PUMA int,
REGION tinyint,
ST tinyint,
ADJHSG int,
ADJINC int,
WGTP int,
NP tinyint,
TYPE tinyint,
ACR tinyint,
AGS tinyint,
BDS tinyint,
BLD tinyint,
BUS tinyint,
CONP smallint,
ELEP smallint,
FS smallint,
FULP int,
GASP int,
HFL tinyint,
INSP varchar(6),
KIT tinyint,
MHP int,
MRGI tinyint,
MRGP int,
MRGT tinyint,
MRGX tinyint,
PLM tinyint,
RMS tinyint,
RNTM tinyint,
RNTP int,
SMP int,
TEL tinyint,
TEN tinyint,
VACS tinyint,
VAL tinyint,
VEH tinyint,
WATP int,
YBL tinyint,
FES tinyint,
FINCP int,
FPARC tinyint,
GRNTP int,
GRPIP tinyint,
HHL tinyint,
HHT tinyint,
HINCP int,
HUGCL bit,
HUPAC tinyint,
HUPAOC tinyint,
HUPARC tinyint,
LNGI tinyint,
MV tinyint,
NOC tinyint,
NPF tinyint,
NPP bit,
NR bit,
NRC tinyint,
OCPIP tinyint,
PARTNER tinyint,
PSF bit,
R18 bit,
R60 tinyint,
R65 tinyint,
RESMODE tinyint,
SMOCP int,
SMX tinyint,
SRNT bit,
SVAL bit,
TAXP tinyint,
WIF tinyint,
WKEXREL tinyint,
WORKSTAT tinyint,
FACRP bit,
FAGSP bit,
FBDSP bit,
FBLDP bit,
FBUSP bit,
FCONP bit,
FELEP bit,
FFSP bit,
FFULP bit,
FGASP bit,
FHFLP bit,
FINSP bit,
FKITP bit,
FMHP bit,
FMRGIP bit,
FMRGP bit,
FMRGTP bit,
FMRGXP bit,
FMVYP bit,
FPLMP bit,
FRMSP bit,
FRNTMP bit,
FRNTP bit,
FSMP bit,
FSMXHP bit,
FSMXSP bit,
FTAXP bit,
FTELP bit,
FTENP bit,
FVACSP bit,
FVALP bit,
FVEHP bit,
FWATP bit,
FYBLP bit,
WGTP1 int,
WGTP2 int,
WGTP3 int,
WGTP4 int,
WGTP5 int,
WGTP6 int,
WGTP7 int,
WGTP8 int,
WGTP9 int,
WGTP10 int,
WGTP11 int,
WGTP12 int,
WGTP13 int,
WGTP14 int,
WGTP15 int,
WGTP16 int,
WGTP17 int,
WGTP18 int,
WGTP19 int,
WGTP20 int,
WGTP21 int,
WGTP22 int,
WGTP23 int,
WGTP24 int,
WGTP25 int,
WGTP26 int,
WGTP27 int,
WGTP28 int,
WGTP29 int,
WGTP30 int,
WGTP31 int,
WGTP32 int,
WGTP33 int,
WGTP34 int,
WGTP35 int,
WGTP36 int,
WGTP37 int,
WGTP38 int,
WGTP39 int,
WGTP40 int,
WGTP41 int,
WGTP42 int,
WGTP43 int,
WGTP44 int,
WGTP45 int,
WGTP46 int,
WGTP47 int,
WGTP48 int,
WGTP49 int,
WGTP50 int,
WGTP51 int,
WGTP52 int,
WGTP53 int,
WGTP54 int,
WGTP55 int,
WGTP56 int,
WGTP57 int,
WGTP58 int,
WGTP59 int,
WGTP60 int,
WGTP61 int,
WGTP62 int,
WGTP63 int,
WGTP64 int,
WGTP65 int,
WGTP66 int,
WGTP67 int,
WGTP68 int,
WGTP69 int,
WGTP70 int,
WGTP71 int,
WGTP72 int,
WGTP73 int,
WGTP74 int,
WGTP75 int,
WGTP76 int,
WGTP77 int,
WGTP78 int,
WGTP79 int,
WGTP80 int)
```

Headers row

> serialno,RT,DIVISION,PUMA,REGION,ST,ADJHSG,ADJINC,WGTP,NP,TYPE,ACR,AGS,BATH,BDSP,BLD,BUS,CONP,ELEP,FS,FULP,GASP,HFL,INSP,MHP,MRGI,MRGP,MRGT,MRGX,REFR,RMSP,RNTM,RNTP,RWAT,SINK,SMP,STOV,TEL,TEN,TOIL,VACS,VALP,VEH,WATP,YBL,FES,FINCP,FPARC,GRNTP,GRPIP,HHL,HHT,HINCP,HUGCL,HUPAC,HUPAOC,HUPARC,KIT,LNGI,MULTG,MV,NOC,NPF,NPP,NR,NRC,OCPIP,PARTNER,PLM,PSF,R18,R60,R65,RESMODE,SMOCP,SMX,SRNT,SVAL,TAXP,WIF,WKEXREL,WORKSTAT,FACRP,FAGSP,FBATHP,FBDSP,FBLDP,FBUSP,FCONP,FELEP,FFSP,FFULP,FGASP,FHFLP,FINSP,FKITP,FMHP,FMRGIP,FMRGP,FMRGTP,FMRGXP,FMVP,FPLMP,FREFRP,FRMSP,FRNTMP,FRNTP,FRWATP,FSINKP,FSMP,FSMXHP,FSMXSP,FSTOVP,FTAXP,FTELP,FTENP,FTOILP,FVACSP,FVALP,FVEHP,FWATP,FYBLP,WGTP1,WGTP2,WGTP3,WGTP4,WGTP5,WGTP6,WGTP7,WGTP8,WGTP9,WGTP10,WGTP11,WGTP12,WGTP13,WGTP14,WGTP15,WGTP16,WGTP17,WGTP18,WGTP19,WGTP20,WGTP21,WGTP22,WGTP23,WGTP24,WGTP25,WGTP26,WGTP27,WGTP28,WGTP29,WGTP30,WGTP31,WGTP32,WGTP33,WGTP34,WGTP35,WGTP36,WGTP37,WGTP38,WGTP39,WGTP40,WGTP41,WGTP42,WGTP43,WGTP44,WGTP45,WGTP46,WGTP47,WGTP48,WGTP49,WGTP50,WGTP51,WGTP52,WGTP53,WGTP54,WGTP55,WGTP56,WGTP57,WGTP58,WGTP59,WGTP60,WGTP61,WGTP62,WGTP63,WGTP64,WGTP65,WGTP66,WGTP67,WGTP68,WGTP69,WGTP70,WGTP71,WGTP72,WGTP73,WGTP74,WGTP75,WGTP76,WGTP77,WGTP78,WGTP79,WGTP80

Row 1

> 2008000000023,H,6,01300,3,01,1012650,1031272,00043,04,1,1,,1,02,02,2,0000,150,2,0002,020,3,00150,,2,00980,1,1,1,03,,,1,1,,1,1,1,1,,0210000,2,0080,09,2,000058100,2,,,4,1,000058100,0,3,3,3,1,1,1,3,02,04,0,0,02,024,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,01170,3,0,1,19,1,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,00112,00045,00068,00017,00044,00091,00071,00032,00036,00042,00048,00041,00013,00031,00063,00013,00037,00017,00063,00098,00026,00036,00017,00065,00036,00020,00014,00035,00037,00046,00047,00048,00080,00034,00012,00061,00031,00069,00043,00060,00011,00050,00016,00057,00050,00013,00016,00068,00056,00039,00042,00049,00081,00041,00012,00092,00050,00055,00049,00016,00062,00041,00103,00012,00048,00060,00073,00052,00063,00038,00047,00040,00017,00040,00059,00020,00042,00010,00038,00018

[Link to ACS 2008-2010 Data Dictionary](http://www.census.gov/acs/www/Downloads/data_documentation/pums/DataDict/PUMS_Data_Dictionary_2008-2010.pdf)

Comment: Surely you aren't using column headers on you cvs file, right?

Comment: There might be a comma that throws the import process off: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520731/bulk-load-data-conversion-error-truncation

Comment: @sammarcow Good thing. Annd the value on your file is actually `"2"` with `"` or just `2`?

Comment: @Lamak, the value is indeed just a 2, which is why I am scratching my head.

Comment: Can you post your table definition and the first row of data of your file?

Comment: @sammarcow open the file in another editor (notepad, wordpad, Scite, geany, etc). Sometimes Excel (default for *.csv) will automatically format as string and remove the `''` in its own view. You can confirm the actual values in a text editor.

Comment: @swasheck data is posted... there's none of that.

Comment: @sammarcow Can you clarify the part where you show us the "headers row"?, you said on a comment earlier that your file didn't have a headers row

Comment: @sammarcow based on what i'm seeing, column 42's value is `0210000` which is most assuredly not a `tinyint`

Comment: @Lamak The Headers row is indeed in the original CSV but not my bulk insert CSV.  I use a program to extract (and remove) the headers row from multiple files at once.  The first row of D:\Adata.csv is in fact data without headers, and I just double checked that. For what it's worth the same error occurs on row 2, 3, 4, 5, not 6.   Rows 1 - 6 all contain single digit numbers, which aligns with the spec in the data dictionary.

Comment: @swasheck, I am piecing these together in Excel, then looking at column AT, which I now know be 46, but appears to be FES.  I'm dropping the table and rerunning the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the datatypes that you're using. [`tinyint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) is only capable of handling integer data from 0 through 255. `0210000` is not within that range.

May I suggest creating a staging table into which you dump this file and create that with all (n)varchars? That way you preserve leading `0`s which may be necessary given the type of data you're analyzing.

From the staging table you can run cleansing operations into a "reporting" structure that will allow you to use more appropriate data types which you can discern with SQL queries to profile your data.

Comment: This is correct.  My create table script was incorrect, causing the discrepancy.