# Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, bcp

I'm importing data from a CSV file using the following procedure:

```
CREATE TABLE #HSCodeHeading (
[ItemID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[CMSChapterID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[HeadingCode] [varchar](2) NOT NULL,
[HeadingDescription] [nvarchar](1125) NOT NULL,
[HeadingDescriptionPT] [nvarchar](1125) NOT NULL,   
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ItemID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,     ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

-- Inserting all the from csv to temproary table using BULK INSERT
EXEC ('BULK INSERT #HSCodeHeading
FROM ''' + @FilePath + '''
WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ''<,>'', ROWTERMINATOR =''\n'', FIRSTROW = 2, KEEPIDENTITY, CODEPAGE = ''ACP'' );');
```

Almost all rows (1227 rows/1229 rows) get imported successfully, however the 2 rows below throw the following error:

> *Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
>    Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 515, column 5 (HeadingDescriptionPT).*

Here are the rows:

Row #1

> *602<,>97<,>18<,>4818<,>Papel dos tipos utilizados para papel de toucador e  para papeis semelhantes,  pasta (Ouate) de celulose ou mantas de fibras de celulose, dos tipos utilizados  para fins domésticos ou sanitários, em rolos, de largura não superior a 36 cm,  ou cortados em forma próprias, lenços incluindo os de demaquilhagem,  toalhas de mão, toalhas de mesa, guardanapos, fraldas para bebés,  pensos e tampões higiénicos, lençóis e artigos semelhantes,  para usos domésticos, de toucador, higiénicos ou hospitalares,  vestuário e seus acessórios, de pasta de papel, papel, pasta (Ouate)  de celulose ou de mantas de fibras de celulose<,>Papel dos tipos utilizados para papel de toucador e  para papeis semelhantes,  pasta (Ouate) de celulose ou mantas de fibras de celulose, dos tipos utilizados  para fins domésticos ou sanitários, em rolos, de largura não superior a 36 cm,  ou cortados em forma próprias, lenços incluindo os de demaquilhagem,  toalhas de mão, toalhas de mesa, guardanapos, fraldas para bebés,  pensos e tampões higiénicos, lençóis e artigos semelhantes,  para usos domésticos, de toucador, higiénicos ou hospitalares,  vestuário e seus acessórios, de pasta de papel, papel, pasta (Ouate)  de celulose ou de mantas de fibras de celulose*

Row #2

> *545<,>91<,>02<,>4202<,>Arcas para viagem , malas e maletas, os estojos para óculos, binóculos,  máquinas fotográficas e de filmar, instrumentos musicais, armas, e artefactos  semelhantes, sacos de viagem, sacos isolantes para géneros alimentícios e bebidas, bolsas de toucador, mochilas, bolsas, sacos para compras (sacolas), carteiras, portamoedas, portacartões, cigarreiras, tabaqueiras, estojos para ferramentas, bolsas e sacos para artigos de desporto, estojos para frascos  ou para jóias, caixas para pó de arroz, estojos para ourivesaria e artefactos  semelhantes, de couro natural ou reconstituído, de folhas de plástico, de matérias têxteis, de fibra vulcanizada ou de cartão, ou  recobertos, no todo o  na maior parte, dessas mesmas matérias ou de papel<,>Arcas para viagem , malas e maletas, os estojos para óculos, binóculos,  máquinas fotográficas e de filmar, instrumentos musicais, armas, e artefactos  semelhantes, sacos de viagem, sacos isolantes para géneros alimentícios e bebidas, bolsas de toucador, mochilas, bolsas, sacos para compras (sacolas), carteiras, portamoedas, portacartões, cigarreiras, tabaqueiras, estojos para ferramentas, bolsas e sacos para artigos de desporto, estojos para frascos  ou para jóias, caixas para pó de arroz, estojos para ourivesaria e artefactos  semelhantes, de couro natural ou reconstituído, de folhas de plástico, de matérias têxteis, de fibra vulcanizada ou de cartão, ou  recobertos, no todo o  na maior parte, dessas mesmas matérias ou de papel*

I'm unable to spot the error since both `[HeadingDescription]`, `[HeadingDescriptionPT]` have similar content.

Any highlight in the direction will be welcome. I've cross-check from other SO questions ([7520731](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520731/bulk-load-data-conversion-error-truncation), [13259028](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13259028/sql-server-bulk-insert-bulk-load-data-conversion-error))

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error is pretty clear: the data you're attempting to insert into column `HeadingDescriptionPT` is **too long**.

That column is defined as `[nvarchar](1125)` -

But the two text blocks are **1222** (#602) and **1470** characters (#545) long ...

Comment: Thanks, for the clarifications. However, how (methods) did you arrived to that number? because various tools used to count the characters found 624 (#602) and 748 (#545).

Comment: @Raymond: just copy&paste into a text editor and see how many characters those text blocks are.... tried it with [TextPad](http://www.textpad.com/), [Notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html), [Geany](http://www.geany.org/) - all return the same info

Comment: Thanks,for your comment you're right. The CSV was meant to have only 5 columns separated by "<,>" as column delimiter but it happened to have 6 columns thus the merging of the last 2 columns(HeadingDescription,HeadingDescriptionPT) into one (HeadingDescriptionPT). Creating there by the error.  Thanks for your help.