# Bulk Insert csv file in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

```
DELETE test1;
BULK INSERT TEST1 FROM 'D:\Monday\Omni\traffic.csv' WITH(FIRSTROW = 2, 
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a');
    SELECT *
    FROM test1;
```

While selecting data type of visit to numeric or int it is showing this error

> "Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 Bulk load data conversion error
>   (truncation) for row 2, column 5 (visit)."

But while changing data type to varchar(40), getting visits like "23232,,,,,,,,,,"

in every row of visit column
and I also checked the csv file formatting is set to "General" for this column
Please help!

Comment: Please show your table definition and (a sample from) your csv file.

Comment: `test1` and `TEST1` are different things

Comment: @dbajtr both are same

Comment: wk varchar()
cat varchar()
subcat varchar()
av varchar()
visit varchar()
and I can't give you sample for confidential purporse
@HoneyBadger

Comment: It wasn't a question, you are selecting from `test1` but inserting into `TEST1`. They are different

Comment: @dbajtr It doest make a difference, I tried

Comment: the issue with your bulk insert is with your data. deleting from a different table you are inserting into is another issue that you will need to fix

Comment: @dbajtr what makes you so certain they are different? It would all depend on collation as to whether the case matters.

Comment: If you cannot show a sample from the actual file, please at least include a sample of similar data.  We don't need the confidential data, but a look at what the data is like would be most useful in trying to help you.

Comment: Can you show us the table definition?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: wk  is for week; cat for categoery like Toys or Electrical; subcat for Subcategory like Accessories; visit for number of visits like1232 or 987766;

I am getting problem with visit @JonathanWillcock

Answer (score 0):

I have found another thread that talked about the same error:

[Bulk load data conversion error (truncation)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520731/bulk-load-data-conversion-error-truncation)

The problem may be that there are text fields with the field separator inside. If your text files are not quoted and there is some comma inside them, that can confuse mess the process and cause this error.